# How to get indices from numpy concatenate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, concatenation

I want to [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) numpy `ndarray`s but with indices also.

That is to say, for

```
>>> np.concatenate([[1,2,3,4], [11,22,33], [4], [435,456]])
```

I want the result `numpy.concatenate` already gives:

```
array([  1,   2,   3,   4,  11,  22,  33,   4, 435, 456])
```

but I **also** want the indices of the input list indcating which element of the input list each element of the output array came from:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

I'm aware of simple recipes based on `np.cumsum` and `np.repeat` that I could use to build the index array myself, but is there a numpy-native way to do it?

Comment: how is `np.repeat` not numpy native?

Comment: I guess "numpy native" is not the correct terminology. What I mean is is there an function or method in numpy that provides the implementation for getting, the index array I'm looking for. Simply finding a solution is trivial, but I want the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straight forward list based solution:

```
In [64]: alist = [[1,2,3,4], [11,22,33], [4], [435,456]]
In [67]: idlist = [[i+1]*len(x) for i,x in enumerate(alist)]
In [68]: np.concatenate(alist)
Out[68]: array([  1,   2,   3,   4,  11,  22,  33,   4, 435, 456])
In [69]: np.concatenate(idlist)
Out[69]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

If the sublists were really long, or were already arrays, a solution using more `numpy` operations might be faster.  But if this is the typical mix of sublists, the list comprehension will probably be faster.  Remember that the input to `concatenate` is a list (even if the input is an array it is treated as a list.)

```
In [73]: timeit idlist = [np.arange(len(x)) for i,x in enumerate(alist)]
6.06 µs ± 224 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [74]: timeit idlist = [[i+1]*len(x) for i,x in enumerate(alist)]
2.98 µs ± 8.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
In [16]: alist = [[1,2,3,4], [11,22,33], [4], [435,456]]

In [17]: my_arrays = [np.array(x) for x in alist]

In [18]: index_arrays = [np.ones((x.shape), dtype=int)*i for i, x in enumerate(my_arrays)]

In [19]: np.concatenate(my_arrays)
Out[19]: array([  1,   2,   3,   4,  11,  22,  33,   4, 435, 456])

In [20]: np.concatenate(index_arrays)
Out[20]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```